# Voltage controlling a SMPS via a potentiometer by Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, potentiometer, programming

I have started a new project. The idea is that in a SMPS we will have the potentiometer at the back so that when we vary the pot the output voltage will change. We are currently doing it manually, but my idea is to have the pot controlled with an Arduino. How can it be made? Please help me I am running out of time.

Comment: You can influence the output feedback voltage with a DAC provided by your Arduino rather than using a potentiometer or do the both. It depends on the controller of your SMPS. Nevertheless you have to be care about the possibilities of your SMPS.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're referring to – without having a datasheet of your SMPS, this is basically impossible to answer. Also, probably really, easiest way would be to get a digitally programmable SMPS instead of the one you have right now – but again, that's just guessing, because without datasheet, nothing can be said.

Comment: Please give some more details about the SMPS like the circuit diagram. If not known, measure the voltages all 3 pins w.r.t. ground.

Answer (score 1):

Digital potentiometers could be an option:
[www.microchip.com/design-centers/data-converters/digital-potentiometer](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/data-converters/digital-potentiometer)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

- Connect a servo to the voltage control knob of the power supply.
- Measure the output voltage with the arduino analogue-to-digital.
- Write a program which turns the knob to the desired voltage.

  - Look at [`Servo`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) and [`ReadAnalogVoltage`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadAnalogVoltage)

You'll need to solve

- the physical connection of the servo to the knob
- the voltage measurement if the voltage isn't directly compatible with the ADC range
- the logic and error conditions

This is a very common problem, and very often people use stepper motors or geared-down DC motors instead of a servo.